# Every group with 1990 elements is solvable

Tags: group-theory, sylow-theory

> Show that every group G with $\#G=1990$ is solvable.

Hello,

I am struggeling with a proof of the statement above.

$1990=2\cdot 5\cdot 199$ these are all prime. Hence we have only one 2, 5 and 199-sylowgroup, which are all normal subgroups.

But how can I construct a sequence of normal subgroups with abelien factorgroups?

Any hint?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How many Sylow $199$-subgroups can it have?

Comment: Just one if I am not mistaken.

Comment: So, it's normal. What do you get when you factor it out?

Comment: 199 is prime, so I can not really factor it out, or do you mean something else?

Comment: He means factoring out the normal subgroup of order 199.

Comment: Ah, ok. You get a group of order 10, which is abelian. That is the hint Mark Bennet gave in his answer. I commented there aswell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: what do you know about groups of order $10$?

Comment: Groups of order 10 are cyclic and therefore abelian. So I can just take the Sequence $G\supset S_{199}\supset\{e\}$, where $S_{199}$ is the Sylow 199-subgroup. Then $G/S_{199}$ is a group of order 10 and abelian.

Comment: @Cornman I think you will also find a dihedral group

Comment: @Cornman Not every group of order 10 is Abelian.

Comment: Ok, I dont know that much about dihedral groups. Since this is a question I found on the internet, I think I might have not the tools to solve this properly.

Comment: @Cornman If you are doing Sylow Theory without knowing about dihedral groups, you are definitely getting a bit ahead of yourself. The dihedral group of order $10$ is the group of symmetries of the regular pentagon, which include reflections and rotations. The rotations form a normal subgroup of order $5$. These are basic examples of groups which you will need to know if you are doing any kind of finite group theory.

Comment: In the lecture I visited the only thing about dihdral groups is that $D_{2n}$ for $n\geq 2$ is solvable (without proof). We did not study that much about finite groups. Close to nothing I guess...